# xlsx File format is not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel, system.io.file

I have used System.IO to export Report in Excel. It is working fine for .xls extension but when I changed extension to .xlsx, it gives an error i.e. Incorrect extension or Incorrect File Format.

```
var grdview = new GridView();
            grdview.DataSource = this.GetSequence();
            grdview.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= Search Report " + Date + " - " + Date1 + ".xls ");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
            htmlWriter.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='13' align='center'><font size='45'>Search Report of Regular Passenger</font></td></tr></table>");
            grdview.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            Response.Output.Write(strWriter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `html` is niether `xls` nor `xlsx`.

For `xls` as an obsolete format Excel tries to fix your problem and check for all formats it supports:

[image: screensot]

But `xlsx` should be `zip` with some `xml`s inside, so the message differs:

[image: screenshot]

**You have to use corresponding library to create real excel files.**

Comment: is there any other way using same library ?

Comment: @Faizan, no all you can do with HtmlTextWriter is create HTML. You can google around, there are many .NET libraries which can generate files in genuine Excel formats. Some of them are free to use.

Comment: @Faizan, use OpenXML and some wrappers over it.